Tan function problem
Why does the Tan function give values for 0, and 30 Degree, but not for the others? Strange behavior?
In[16]:= Tan[0 Degree]
Out[16]= 0
In[23]:= Tan[10 Degree]
Out[23]= Tan[10 °]
In[24]:= Tan[20 Degree]
Out[24]= Tan[20 °]
In[19]:= Tan[30 Degree]
Out[19]= 1/Sqrt[3]

Given exact input the result will be exact. If Mathematica does not know a simpler form, then the unevaluated form is the only known exact result. To force a numeric evaluation (albeit approximate), use N, e.g., Tan[10  Degree] // N

You could use Tan[x + y] // TrigExpand // Together to split Tan[x + y] into Sin and Cos pieces each of which Mathematica knows how to simplify (using FunctionExpand). For instance, Tan[20 Degree] can be split as Tan[8 Degree + 12 Degree], and then FunctionExpand can be used to expand each of the resulting pieces.

Isn't this question  art for art's sake?

How about the following?
ToRadicals[Tan[10  *Pi/180]]


-((I (-1 + (-1)^(1/9)))/(1 + (-1)^(1/9)))

RootReduce[%]//ToRadicals


\[Sqrt](3 - (2 I 3^(1/6))/(1/2 (3 + I Sqrt[3]))^( 1/3) - (2/3)^(2/3) (3 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/3) + ( I 2^(2/3) (3 + I Sqrt[3])^(1/3))/3^(1/6) -  2/(3/2 (3 + I Sqrt[3]))^(1/3))

I think the complex unit I cannot be got rid of: RootReduce results in Root[-1 + 33 #1^2 - 27 #1^4 + 3 #1^6 &, 4, 0] and it is known that the polynomial equation of  the third degree cannot be solved in radicals  without I.

This might not be helpful, but you can ComplexExpand the answer in your first codeblock and take the real part (since we know tan(10 deg) is real) and then convert back to radicals to get an answer without I:
ans = ToRadicals[Tan[10*Pi/180]];
$$ $$
justRe = ToRadicals[Tan[10*Pi/180]] // ComplexExpand // Re;
$$ $$
justRe // ToRadicals // Simplify
giving $$ -\frac{(-1)^{7/18} \left((-1)^{2/9}-1\right)}{2+\sqrt[9]{-1}-(-1)^{8/9}} $$
But this might not actually be an improvement, since imaginary stuff  is still implicitly there in places like $\sqrt[9]{-1} $ in the answer

@ydd: Unfortunately, this is not helpful: ComplexExpand[-((I (-1 + (-1)^(1/9)))/(1 + (-1)^(1/9)))] returns trig functions.

Yes, but if you take the Re part and go back ToRadicals and Simplify, you get an output without an explicit I
ComplexExpand[-((I  (-1 + (-1)^(1/9)))/(1 + (-1)^(1/9)))] // Re //    ToRadicals // Simplify
I agree It's probably not helpful though, because it just seems like it's replacing the I parts with various powers of -1.
